Image in header stops scaling when resolution is too small
I'm currently working on a website and I have an image in my header. It's a placeholder right now but the problem is when I shrink the page down to the resolution of a phone, the image stops scaling down and then starts getting cut off.

I've been trying to change some header options and the image will always scale to fit the screen when its getting bigger, but it doesn't want to scale when it gets smaller. Provided is a string of code that just has the header and the navbar. In this example code the header still has the same problem. Ignore the fact that it scales too big if you open it on fullscreen the actual full program forces it to be smaller usually.
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> <!--Direction left to right in english-->

<head> <!--random data like faviicon, .css file location, and site name-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Works in progress</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/favicontest.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hazelhen.neocities.org/NewLook/looks.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headerArea">
            <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    :root {
    --header-image: url('https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/headertest.png');

    /* colors */
    --content: #43256E;
}



body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d19dfc;
    /* you can delete the line below if you'd prefer to not use an image */
    background-size: 160px;
    color: #fceaff;
    background-image: url('https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/bgrose.gif');
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
    position: unset;
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    /* this is only for a background image! */
    /* if you want to put images IN the header, 
you can add them directly to the <div id="header"></div> element! */
    background-image: var(--header-image);
    background-size: cover;
}

#flex {
    display: flex;
}

</style>



So you want the background image for the header to shrink down when you either scale the window/device/page size up or down, correct?

Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm having no problem with the header image scaling when the page size is increased, problem is coming from when page size is decreased.

let me know if the below answer resolves your issue

the problem being that background-image doesn't give height to the element thus making hard for the picture to scale 100% width while adapting the height to the aspect ratio coming from the picture itself. This is true even by using background-size like cover .. yet because that's supposed to cover an initial height given. There are tricks inferring the ratio but it's convoluted. Also height: fit-content is a trick that wouldn't work because it's not strictly a content. There are plenty of questions here revolving around this of the like background image with 100% width .

another approach could be using an actual <img> element that will work appropriately in those regards. But since you used the css variable trick for its url it would need added js to set that url taken from css variable

by the way I wanted also to point out that you described the problem in a way that's not very accurate. Your current solution fails also when scaling up by cropping the bottom side of the picture because you imposed a fixed height

Here's a simple solution according to what I understood from your question. I have changed the background size to contain, to always contain the background. Also changed the background position/repeat behavior.
Edit: If you still want the header background to take the full background width, you can update the #header section to the following:
#header {
    position: unset;
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    /* this is only for a background image! */
    /* if you want to put images IN the header, 
you can add them directly to the <div id="header"></div> element! */
    background-image: var(--header-image);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}



 :root {
    --header-image: url('https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/headertest.png');

    /* colors */
    --content: #43256E;
}



body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', "Lucida Console", monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #d19dfc;
    /* you can delete the line below if you'd prefer to not use an image */
    background-size: 160px;
    color: #fceaff;
    background-image: url('https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/bgrose.gif');
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
    position: unset;
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    /* this is only for a background image! */
    /* if you want to put images IN the header, 
you can add them directly to the <div id="header"></div> element! */
    background-image: var(--header-image);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#flex {
    display: flex;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr"> <!--Direction left to right in english-->

<head> <!--random data like faviicon, .css file location, and site name-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Works in progress</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://hazelhen.neocities.org/Imagess/favicontest.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hazelhen.neocities.org/NewLook/looks.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headerArea">
            <div id="header"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>




It works in concept, but what I was trying for was what I have in my code right now, but when it scales down it continues to shrink. Either that or maybe have the header become centered when it crops itself.

@HazelVee I see, maybe I misunderstood your question. That said, I think you can have the desired effect with header in the middle & the background image cropping with the edit part I added.

Did some more tests and decided on using background-position: center center;
and then cropped the image itself. Code although still not scaling when smaller centers at the middle, which I can deal with for now. Cropped image too so it fits more
#header {
position: unset;
height: 120px;
width: auto;
background-image: var(--header-image);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;

}

if you replied to my comments trying to understand what I meant with my words, there's a solution to achieve the result you are aiming to
